# How can I run Apache Http Server?

Tags: apache, webserver

I am using Windows 7(32-bit OS).I downloaded **httpd-2.4.4-win32-ssl_0.9.8.zip** using the following [link](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/)

[image]

The followed same rules,According to the following [link](http://www.premiumwebbloghosting.com/2013/02/manually-installing-apache-server-on-windows-7.html)

I got following error while server starting time.

```
 <OS 10048> Only one usage of each socket address <protocol/network address/port> is normally permitted. :make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, Shutting down.
```

so, I changed port number in **Apache/conf/httpd.config** following way.

Find the Server Root:

```
Listen 80
```

Changed it to :

```
Listen 20
```

Find server root:

#ServerName www.example.com:80

Changed it to :

```
ServerName localhost:20
```

after this, I Re-installed .This time I didn't get any errors.I started server and open the following URL in browser but it's not working.

```
http://localhost/20
```

for my conformation,I open **cmd** and typed **netstat -a -o**. it showing port 20 is activating state.

How can i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use official Apache binaries from http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22 ?

Comment: @mvp I tried with official Apache binaries,it shows the following error while initialization time.
`httpd is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file.`. I searched in Google for this,I found this `http://serverfault.com/questions/238379/httpd-command-line-not-recognized`.He suggested set path. I don't know where is `httpd.exe` file. can you suggest me.

Comment: On windows it is installed as system service. You start it using `net start apache2.2`, and stop using `net stop apache2.2`

Comment: @mvp can you explain clearly.can I set the `path` in environment variables.

Comment: You do not need to set `PATH`. If you installed Apache from official MSI, `net start apache2.2` works out of the box

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33126/discussion-between-ur-truly-friend-and-mvp)